# Xamarin Forms - Image element disappearing under button element onclick in absolute layout

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, layout, element

I have an absolutelayout which has a Button and an Image laid into the same space, with the image coming second to be on top. Its just to position the image where i like on the button rather than where it goes using ImageSource attribute.

This works fine when the page is shown originally, but once you press one of those buttons, the image that was overtop disappears. Its almost like it falls behind in Z order or something - however in the OnClick method I tried doing

```
AbsoluteLayout.RaiseChild(image);
```

as well as

```
AbsoluteLayout.Children.Remove(image);
AbsoluteLayout.Children.Insert(0, image);
```

but neither seems to bring it back to visibility.

Is this just an oversight somewhere on my part, or is there a trick to keeping the image on top (or visible, if its not a depth issue)[image]

Comment: Hi, not too much understanding the issue, could you share a gif to explain the problem?

Comment: Thanks for updating a gif, I will check in my local site. In addition, you also could share the code of `Button` and `Image` in **Xaml**.

Comment: Hi, I have updated an answer, you could have a look when you have time. If the reply is helpful, please do not forget to accept it as answer( click the ✔ in the upper left corner of this answer) and vote it up, it will help others who have similar issue.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is caused by **[Fast Renderers in Xamarin Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/internals/fast-renderers)**.

You could enable the legacy renderers by adding the following line of code to your `MainActivity` class before calling `Forms.Init`:

```
Forms.SetFlags("UseLegacyRenderers");
```

Here is my Xaml code:

```
<AbsoluteLayout x:Name="myAbsoluteLayout">
    <Button Text="Button"
            BackgroundColor="LightBlue"
            Clicked="Button_Clicked"
            x:Name="button"
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5,0,100,50"
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional" />
    <Image x:Name="firstImage"
            Source="icon.png"
            InputTransparent="False"
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5,0,25,25"
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional" />
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

The effect:

[image]